# Shortest way to convert an integer to a full hour time offset?

Tags: php

In my application the user can select an hour-based time zone offset from GMT using an integer value. I want to convert this integer into a string representation:

```
echo getTZOffset(4); // "+04:00"
echo getTZOffset(-1); // "-01:00"
```

It can be easily done separately, e.g.:

```
echo sprintf('+%02d:00', 4); // positive
echo sprintf('-%02d:00', abs(-1)); // negative
```

But is there an easier way?

Comment: How do you plan to handle UTC offsets which aren't whole hours? India, for example...

Comment: @JonSkeet I only care about whole hours in this particular case :)

Comment: Have you tried using DateTime? You've got there `getOffset()`.

Comment: @JonSkeet It gets even weirder with countries like Nepal, with their +05:45 offset.

Comment: After extensive clarifications with @Jack, the only conclusion is: Can this be done as a *one-liner* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf('%+03d:00', $num);
```

The `+` is an optional *sign specifier* prefixing both positive and negative numbers.